# Split axis into sub categories

Tags: powerbi

Is it possible to do something like below picture in power bi? I've tried looking around, but with no luck. Maybe by the use of hierachy?

[image]

This was made in excel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's achievable in Power BI.

Sample data:

[image: data]

Create a column chart with `Region` and `Category` as `Axis` and `Value` as `Value` (Note that `Region` is placed above `Category` to identify the hierarchy):

[image: column chart 1]

And expand all down one level in the hierarchy:

[image: column chart 2]

Now if you go to `Format` and switch off `Concatenate labels`:

[image: column chart 3]

Comment: @Noxan Ng Thank you! Thanks for a very using images aswell :)